# Show that $p=2^k+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

When $p$ is an odd prime and $a=Re \left ( e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{p}} \right)$ then $[\mathbb{Q}(a) : \mathbb{Q}]=\frac{p-1}{2}$.

Let $\theta = \frac{2 \pi}{p}$.

If $\sin{\theta}$ is a constructable number show that $p=2^k+1$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

So that $\sin{\theta}$ is a constructable number, the degree of $Irr(\sin{\theta}, \mathbb{Q})$ should be a power of $2$.

Isn't $\sin{\theta}$ the imaginary part of $e^{\frac{2 \pi }{p}}$ ?? How can we use $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}(a)]$ ??

Answer (score 1):

If a complex number on the unit circle or any of its components is constructible (by compass and straightedge), all three are constructible. Each construction creates a point in either the earlier extension or some quadratic extension, and so if $a$ is constructible the degree of the final extension $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a power of 2. Since $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}] = \frac{p-1}{2}$, you get the result you are looking for.

Comment: Could you explain me further why it stands that if a complex number or any of its components is constructible then all three are constructible??

Comment: I forgot to say "unit". You have 0 and 1, with which you can draw the real and imaginary axes as well as the unit circle. So if you have a point on the unit circle you can drop perpendiculars to get the components, and conversely if you have one of the components you can get the two possible complex numbers it could have been.